# Fixing unknown permission in Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ownership

I caught permissions problem on my web application file inside Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL)

My System are :
Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 64bit

I run my web server in ubuntu, when I print list directory with non-sudo account, it show as below :

```
raydeon@LAPTOP-HF68R0VG:/var/www/html/fin-app/application/modules/accounting/controllers# ls -la 
ls: cannot access 'application/modules/accounting/controllers/Account.php': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'application/modules/accounting/controllers/Account_receivable.php': Permission denied
total 0
drw-r--r-- 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:15 ..
-????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? Account.php
-????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? Account_receivable.php
```

When I print with sudo, it show as below :

```
root@LAPTOP-HF68R0VG:/var/www/html/fin-app/application/modules/accounting/controllers$ ls -la 
total 0
drw-r--r-- 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- ? raydeon raydeon 2247 Oct  7 10:58 Account.php
-rw-r--r-- ? raydeon raydeon 3103 Oct  7 10:58 Account_receivable.php
```

I have try fix permission with :

```
sudo chmod -R 644 *
```

and ownership with :

```
sudo chown -hR raydeon:raydeon *
```

It's doesn't help, it's still have an unknown permissions when I print list by non sudo account

```
raydeon@LAPTOP-HF68R0VG:/var/www/html/fin-app/application/modules/accounting/controllers# ls -la 
ls: cannot access 'application/modules/accounting/controllers/Account.php': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'application/modules/accounting/controllers/Account_receivable.php': Permission denied
total 0
drw-r--r-- 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 raydeon raydeon 4096 Oct  9 11:15 ..
-????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? Account.php
-????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? Account_receivable.php
```

it's still can't access by non-sudo account, although the ownership properties is raydeon (non-sudo), it happen to a lot of file inside modules folder. Thanks!

Comment: Does that file actually exist? Try to open that folder with WSL network share `\\wsl$` in File Explorer.

Comment: it's exist, but I have found the solution for that weird error, here https://askubuntu.com/questions/243999/why-do-question-mark-characters-appear-when-changing-the-permissions-of-director

thanks @Biswapriyo